# Integarting SQL server with SNMP for sending alerts to 3rd party applications

Tags: sql-server

We do have 4 SQL servers(2012) and there is no monitoring tool as of now. Can we install the SNMP agent in the sql servers so that SNMP will send traps to my incident or ticketing tool, if any error or failures occurs? Or else what is the best approach i can go with to get alerts as tickets for failures and errors?
Can someone help me in this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A better option would be to set alerts on your sql servers , alerts only about the things that you really care about, CPU utilization, for failed SQL Agent jobs, failed backup jobs etc. Do not create alert for everything as it will generate too much noise and you may miss something important in that noise something that you really care about.

Comment: So are you saying we can integrate SQL servers with SNMP?

Comment: I am saying use SQL Server's built-in Alerts. Very easy to create and manage.

Comment: Will that SQL Server's built-in Alerts creates ticket or incident in third party application or it will send just email alert?

Comment: Email alerts only.

Comment: So we need to create tickets manually? Right!

Comment: I dont know, what ITIL software you are using, but some do create tickets automatically as soon as there is an email. Have a look maybe you can configure your ITIL tool to generate these tickets automatically as soon as an email is received. But really do you really want to create a ticket every time there is an alert? Sometimes the alerts are there to only ALERT you and do nothing. You dont want to create a ticket every time your SQL Server CPU spikes to 100% but you definitely need to be alerted when it happens.